# How to do just one query for something like this

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I am trying to efficienty process this

```
mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET value = '" . time() . "' WHERE setting='roundtime'");
mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET value = '" . $curusers . "' WHERE setting='currentusers'");
mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET value = '" . $settingNum. "' WHERE setting='settingNum'");
```

I've been using INNER JOIN and other things for select's but I have no idea how I would use UPDATE for something in this structure.

Comment: NO thats wrong, I'm trying to update all the cells at once in different WHERE's

Comment: NO, it's not duplicate of the mentioned post at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can write the query as follows:

```
UPDATE settings
    set value = (case when setting = 'currentusers' then '" . $curusers . "'
                      when setting = 'roundtime' then '" . time() . "' 
                      when setting = 'settingNum' then '" . $settingNum. "'
                 end)
    where setting in ('roundtime', 'currentusers', 'settingNum');
```

There are several issues.  Glossing over the fact that mysql_ functions are deprecated and you should be using parameters, there is also a SQL issue.  You are storing different types of data in `value` -- a time plus whatever the other two are.  This doesn't seem like a good design of the database.  Is there are reason why these are not columns in a table?